# how to display class data members stored in multimap

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

here is the code

```
class student
{
int num;
string name;
float marks;
public:
void add()
{
    cout << "Enter the num name and marks:" << endl;
    cin >> num >> name >> marks;
}
void display()
{
    cout << num << endl;
    cout << name << endl;
    cout << marks << endl;
}
};
void main()
{
student ss;
multimap<int,student> st;
multimap<int,student>::iterator itr;
    ss.add();
    st.insert(make_pair(1000, ss));

for (itr = st.begin(); itr != st.end(); itr++)
{
    cout << itr->second; // its showing ERROR 
}
}
```

the error is 
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'student' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    firstmultimap
how to fix this

Comment: Someone has to write an `operator<<` for `student`. It's not done automatically.

Comment: sorry sir but i am very new to it can you tell me the syntax

Comment: You need `<<` operator. `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const student& obj)
{
    // write obj to stream;
    return os;
}`

Answer (score 0):

To display the student object you need to overload `<<` operator.

I have made the operator overloading function friend of `student` class so it could be called without creating an object.

Also, check this example on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx).

**Example:**

---

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class student
{
private:
    int num;
    string name;
    float marks;
public:
    void add()
    {
        cout << "Enter the num name and marks:" << endl;
        cin >> num >> name >> marks;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout << num << endl;
        cout << name << endl;
        cout << marks << endl;
    }
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &output, const student &s)
    {
        output << "Num: " << s.num << "\nName: " << s.name << "\nMarks: " << s.marks << endl;
        return output;
    }
};

int main()
{
    student ss;
    multimap<int, student> st;
    multimap<int, student>::iterator itr;
    ss.add();
    st.insert(make_pair(1000, ss));
    for (itr = st.begin(); itr != st.end(); itr++)
    {
        cout << itr->second;
    }
    // Using Range based for loop
    // for(const auto &i : st)
    //     cout << i.second;
    return 0;
}
```